# Scrollbar on iframe Not Animating in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, iframe, scrollbar

Am I doing something wrong, or are iframe scroll bars broken in Chrome. Have a simple page with iframe here demonstrating the issue:

http://chuckskoda.com/iframe-scroll

The iframe is scrollable from a scroll wheel or trackpad gesture, and when the scroll bar appears you can actually click and drag as usual. **Only the scroll bar doesn't animate in Chrome (Version 37.0.2062.94 for OS X).** It stays in it's initial position anchored at the top of the frame.

The scroll bars function and animate as expected in both the latest Safari and Firefox.

Is this a bug in Chrome? If so, how should I bring it to the attention of the team?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that it seems to work fine if you remove the "overflow: scroll" style from the iframe (I think it's somewhat redundant with the scrolling=yes).  Still seems likely to be a bug to me though, tracking here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=384154

Answer (score 0):

I'm also experiencing this issue with a frameset, no solution found yet.

Google Chrome is called [Chromium](http://code.google.com/chromium/) on Google Code

The [Chromium Bug Reporting Page](http://dev.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines) is there and has the link to submit bugs listed. (Google Account Required)